# Getting error while executing procedure using knex js

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js

Getting an error while trying to execute procedure using **knex.js**

**Code**:

```
var procedureName = 'TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_PRC';
var bindingsParamString = '?, ?';
var bindingsParamValueStringArray = [
{ type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,val:5},
{ type: oracledb.DATE, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
];
var rawQuery= 'BEGIN ' + procedureName + ' ( ' + bindingsParamString +' ) 
END;';
knex.raw(rawQuery, bindingsParamValueStringArray)
 .then(data => {done(null, data);})
.catch(err => {done(err);});
```

Getting error like

> Error : TypeError: BEGIN TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_PRC(:1, :2); 
>       END; - expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]

Found a thread in git also https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1901 but no solution has been provided. Please help

Comment: Seems there's a long-standing issue in Knex.js that needs to be addressed. In the meantime, why not just use the driver directly?

Comment: Thanks are you talking about oracle driver? i got a tweek in the library which is working as of now.May be have ti use some kind of wrapper

Comment: Looks like nobody has cared about this feature enough to actually add support for it to knex (0.16). Maybe someday someone will send pull request for supporting it. I would happily merge it :)

Comment: same here i am using                                                                                                      
     if (obj.method == 'raw') {
             return resolver({
             response : outBinds
            });
         } and its working but not a correct way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same here i am using

```
if (obj.method == 'raw') {
    return resolver({
      response: outBinds
    });
  }
```

and its working but not a correct way to do it